Creation of streaming dataset is deprecated. We recommend exploring Real-Time Intelligence in Microsoft Fabric
Suddenly I can not create new dataset schema for power bi report in Azure. While trying to create new dataset schema via rest API it is showing me error. The error is :
"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"FeatureDeprecatedError\",\"pbi.error\":{\"code\":\"FeatureDeprecatedError\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"LearnMoreLink\",\"detail\":{\"type\":0,\"value\":\"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming#types-of-real-time-semantic-models\"}},{\"code\":\"FeatureDeprecatedMessage\",\"detail\":{\"type\":0,\"value\":\"Creation of streaming dataset is deprecated. We recommend exploring Real-Time Intelligence in Microsoft Fabric.\"}}],\"exceptionCulprit\":1}}}"


In previous it worked fine, from today suddenly occurred this error.

You've hit the date the deprecation results in an error so you need to move to Fabric or find another solution.

Do you know when it was announced about deprecation ?

Not long ago, see https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-retirement-of-real-time-streaming-in-power-bi/. Existing solutions will be supported until 2027


Creation of streaming dataset is deprecated. We recommend exploring Real-Time Intelligence in Microsoft Fabric.

I agree with Peter's bon comment on the MS-Document by Shannon Lindsay.

Microsoft recently announced the retirement of real-time streaming datasets in Power BI.
Existing real-time semantic models in Power BI will not be retired until October 2027.
Microsoft is encouraging users to move to Microsoft Fabric.
Fabric is a newer platform that combines Power BI with advanced data capabilities, especially suited for handling real-time data in a more powerful way.
Also, they informed that additional guidance in an upcoming post.

Reference:
What is Real-Time Intelligence - Microsoft Fabric | Microsoft Learn
